# Java Allowed Narrowing Reference Conversion

Tags: java, types, type-conversion, subtyping

I am referencing section 5.1.6.1 of the JLS (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/jls13.pdf).

At point 2, it says that "If there exists a parameterized type X that is a supertype of T, and a parameterized type Y that is a supertype of S, such that the erasures of X and Y are the same, then
X and Y are not provably distinct".

Now, let's assume that `T := List<Object>`, `S := List<String>`, and we write `T = S;` which gives a compilation error. But that is not in line with the afore-mentioned quote. If we choose `X := List<?>` which is a parameterized type and a supertype of `List<Object>`, and we choose `Y := List<?>`, then the erasures of `X` and `Y` are the same (`List`).

Where am I misinterpreting the rule?

Comment: Yes, I read that too and considered it to be an implication of the quote. Their example can be summarised to: If S and T are provably distinct, then narrowing reference conversion is not allowed. However, they formulate the quoted rule and I cannot put it together.

Comment: List<"?"> is a direct supertype of List<"Object">, since the type argument "?" contains the type argument "Object" (cf. 4.5.1).

Comment: `List<String>` is **not** a subtype of `List<Object>`.

Comment: @user85421 Indeed, it does. You just need to apply the rules for subtyping.

Comment: The specification doesn’t say that you can pick arbitrary combination of X and Y that suits your case. It says “if there exist…then…” defining a condition that must always hold (for all existing X and Y).